# Is it possible to write tests for mobile native apps using appium and nightwatchjs?

Tags: selenium, appium, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to write tests for mobile native apps using appium and nightwatchjs?

I found a lot of resources for web automation but not a single one for Native mobile apps. Official docs also not saying anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

There is lot of mobile native app automation tools and documents available in market,

Please find below tools, supported platforms and its documentation

1.Appium

```
Native : Android & iOS  
Mobile web app : Android chrome & iOS safari
```

Documentation link :http://appium.io/documentation.html?lang=en

2.Calabash

```
Native only : Android & iOS
```

Website : http://calaba.sh/

Setup Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykZ3HIYOOnQ

3.Robotium

```
Native only : Android only
```

Github wiki Documenation : https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Getting-Started

4.Espresso

```
Native only : Android only
```

Documentation link : https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/

5.Webdriver.io

```
Native : Android & iOS
Mobile web app : Android chrome & iOS
```

Note : Internally it’s pointing to appium only

Documentation link : http://webdriver.io/

6.Selendroid

```
Native : Android only
Mobile web app : Android only
```

Documentation link : http://selendroid.io/

7.Python uiautomator

```
Native : Android only
```

Github link : https://github.com/xiaocong/uiautomator

Above tools are widely used in mobile app automation currently.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Selendroid or Appium for testing Native apps, If you are good with the Selenium Webdriver go for this. because Selendroid and Appium are using similar Selenium codes.

Using Appium you can test both ios and Android native apps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRddxh-4u5k

Selendroid is mainly for Android Apps
follow this tutorial
http://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selendroid.html
These are two links i found most suitable for learning these technologies. hope this will help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

For native app testing, you must change `launch_url` to `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub`, `port` to `4723` and keep `browserName` empty.

You may follow the following tutorial to get an idea about native app testing using Nightwatchjs:

https://www.utest.com/articles/android-native-app-testing-by-nightwatchjs

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not post some tool or library as answer. This post demonstrates how to write tests for mobile native apps using appium and nightwatchjs. I guess it won't be wise to copy and paste the content of the post here.

Comment: @Sakib You should summarize some of the key points or some of the things to pay attention to etc. Because link-only posts are very likely to get flagged and then deleted by reviewers. Posting a link is easy but giving your post some additional value requires more effort and also makes it more valuable which is what the folks on this site are trying to accomplish.